# How to use regular expression in multiple lines

Tags: regex, csv, python-3.x

I have got a csv file like this:

```
XXXX,YYYYY,41.29942,2.19939,2013-05-21T10:22:35+0000
XXXX,YYYYY,41.2679,2.08318,2013-05-21T10:42:25+0000
XXXX,YYYYY,41.23117,1.99121,2013-05-21T11:03:39+0000
XXXX,YYYYY,41.15553,1.93085,2013-05-21T11:27:40+0000
```

and I´m using the following script

```
import re

ruta = 'C:\filename.csv'

with open(ruta,'r') as fh:
    lector = fh.read()
    pat = re.compile(r'^(XXXX,YYYYY,([0-9]{0,2}.[0-9]{0,7}),(-?)([0-9]{0,2}.[0-9]{0,7})),([0-9]{0,4}-[0-9]{0,2}-[0-9]{0,2}.[0-9]{0,2})T([0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2})(\+0000)\n')
    res = re.findall(pat,lector)
print(res)
```

But just find the first group. 
I know that I can use the csv module, but I think that is easier to process by groups, because some lines are latitude and longitude positions.

I´m trying either `search`, `findall` and `finditer` but only the first line returned.

Maybe something about multiline, but I can´t understand that.

Comment: You are requiring that the day section of a date ends in `.` and an optional 1 or 2 digit number. You are using `.[0-9]{0,2}` in the pattern before the `T`.

Comment: Really, a regular expression is not the tool to use here. Just use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify any flag, by default `^` matches the beginning of the string.

Specify [`re.M` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) (or `re.MULTILINE`) to match them at the beginning of the line.

```
pat = re.compile(r'^....', flags=re.M)
```